# Polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, convention

While locating the polar coordinates of a point, why do we take the initial line as a directed line? Doesn't it suffice to mention that the angle that it makes will be measured with the positive direction of the $x$ axis? 
 Couldn't we just take a line *segment*?

Comment: What do you think "a directed line" (?) means? A directed *vector* is a segment of line with a definite direction, however you define that.

Comment: I never make any mention to directed lines when I look at polar coordinates, I _do_ just say the argument is the angle it makes with the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know what a vector _is_. It's a directed line segment. But could we do without using a vector while specifying a polar coordinate?  Could we not talk of a _directed_ line segment and simply use a line segment?

Comment: @BillWallis Most textbooks start by using the angle made by a _directed_ line segment to define the argument. What I'm asking is couldn't we do without assigning a direction to the initial line segment? We are already saying that the angle is made with the positive direction of the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I'd like to ask this : **How do we define a vector completely?**

We usually do so by defining three things.

1. It's **sense**
2. The **angle** it makes with a certain reference axis.
3. It's **point of application**

What I can infer is, you intend to ask that if we have defined the sense of the vector, why is there a need to specify the angle conventions, and vice versa.

I believe that the word directed segment itself implies that one of these things have to be defined. What the text means to say is that we take a segment, we measure the angle from the positive x, which makes the segment into a directed one.